# scanf for multiple characters in sublime text 3

Tags: character, scanf, sublimetext3

I have a strange problem in sublime text 3

When I use `scanf` to scan one character , it works fine ..

```c
int main()
{

    char num;

    printf("enter a number : ");

    scanf("%d",&num);

    printf("%d\n",num);

    return 0;
}
```

> output :enter a number : 15
>
> 15

But when I use it for two characters , there is a problem that 
the first number is always zero !

```c
int main()
{

    char num1,num2;

    printf("enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&num1,&num2);
    printf("%d %d\n",num1,num2);
    return 0;
}
```

> output :enter a number : 15 10
>
> 0 10

if I replaced a `char` by `int` in declaration it works fine ..

I tested these two codes on code blocks and they worked fine ..
Sublime Text 3 works in a perfect way for compiling c codes but this problem is strange !.

I have a build system for sublime text 3 :

```json
{

    "cmd": ["gcc", "-Wall", "-ansi", "-std=c11" ,  "$file_name", "-o", 

    "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/k" , "$file_base_name"],

    "selector": "source.c",

    "working_dir": "${file_path}",

    "shell": true    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short: your code is technically broken, and you need to use `int` and not `char` here; the fact that it works in some places and not in Sublime is unrelated. If you manually compile your code outside of Sublime using the same command that the build system is using, you'll get the same result.

For the particulars of your problem, the `scanf` function documentation has this to say about the `%d` format specifier:

> d: Matches an optionally signed decimal integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to int.

An `int` is not the same size as a `char` when represented in memory. According to the language specification, a `char` is the smallest addressable unit of the machine that can contain basic character data, which is generally a byte.

On the other hand, an `int` has to be capable of containing **at least** the range `-32,767` to `+32,767`, which means it has to be a minimum of 16 bits (two bytes), although it can be more.

You can see the relative sizes of them on your particular computer using this simple program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("char=%d\nint=%d\n", sizeof(char), sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

If you run that, you're going to notice that the `char` is smaller than the `int`.

Now, going back to `scanf`, it assumes that if you use `%d` it's going to get a pointer to an `int`, so when it decodes the number and stores it into the first pointer you gave it, it's going to store the number of bytes that are in an `int`.

Since the `char` and the `int` aren't the same size, what that does is store the first `char` size of bytes into the variable that you provided, and then write the rest of them over top of adjacent memory, clobbering it.

Variables on the stack (such as your variables in your program) are stored adjacent to each other in memory. So when the first value is stored, some of the bytes clobber adjacent memory, then the second value is stored also clobbering over adjacent memory, and in that case the memory contains the character of the first item, making it's value 0.

You'll notice different random results by using larger numbers. For example, try it while entering the numbers `0` and `32767`.

As I mentioned above, this is not a Sublime problem; Sublime doesn't compile your code, the compiler does, Sublime just lets you edit it. If this works anywhere else, it's due to the compiler generating the code differently in a way that's masking the problem for you.

For example, if the code was compiled to align everything on the stack to 4 byte boundaries and `int` is 4 bytes on your computer, then the problem still exists if you use `char`, but since the bytes being clobbered don't represent anything, you don't see any outward effect.

You mention in your question that this works if you enter a single number; that's because you don't have anything obvious for the bug in your code to corrupt.

Try running the following variation.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{    
    int a = 100; 
    char num; 
    int b = 200; 

    printf("enter a number : ");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    printf("%d %d %d\n",num, a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

---

To address your comment on this answer w/regards to wanting to use `char` because you want the smaller range for the values that you're using (date parts), the appropriate way to do that is to use `int` (which `scanf` requires) and check the values you get out to see if they're in range.

In particular, `scanf` just grabs a number and stores it, but doesn't do any checking. So even though you expect the value to be say between `1` and `31` for a month, you still need to guard against the user entering a `0` or anything `32` and above.

If you really want your variables to be `char`, you need to first use `scanf` to store them into an `int` and then assign the values to your resulting `char` while you're checking that they're in range (since an `int` can hold a bigger number than a `char`).

---

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation and efforts .. In fact .. i know the difference between `char` and `int` addressing in memory but in my case i want to use `char` for only 255 numbers for a code that takes a day and month from a user and `int` for a year .. For codes you provided .. >>output : char=1 >>int=4 And for the second code : >>output :enter a number : 15 >>15 100 0 .. I noticed when i build your code in code blocks with ( build target : Debug (not release) ) the output has the same problem of sublime ! What do you think to solve this problem ?

Comment: You'll need to make the variables `int` and then check after `scanf` returns to make sure that they're in the range you want and display an error if they're not. Even if you could get it to store the value into a `char`, it would overflow if the user entered a number bigger than 255.